# Is it possible to make a nested FOREACH without COGROUP in PigLatin?

Tags: foreach, nested, apache-pig

I want to use the FOREACH like:

```
a:{a_attr:chararray}
b:{b_attr:int}

FOREACH a {
  res = CROSS a, b;
  -- some processing
  GENERATE res;
}
```

By this I mean to make for each element of `a` a cross-product with all the elements of `b`, then perform some custom filtering and return tuples.

==EDIT==

Custom filetering = res_filtered = FILTER res BY ...;
GENERATE res_filtered.

==EDIT-2==
How to do it with a nested CROSS no more no less inside a FOR loop without prior GROUP or COGROUP?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish.  What kind of processing is this "custom filtering"?

Comment: Perhaps some sample input and output would help clarify.

Comment: But what does `CROSS` mean in this context?  You are only processing a single record of `a` at a time. I'll post an answer for what I think you want, but I may still be missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the specifics of your filtering, you may be able to design a limited set of disjoint classes of elements in `a` and `b`, and then `JOIN` on those.  For example:

If your filtering rules are

- if `a_attr` starts with "Foo" and `b` is 4, accept
- if `a_attr` starts with "Bar" and `b` is greater than 17, accept
- if `a_attr` begins with a letter in [m-z] and `b` is less than 0, accept
- otherwise, reject

Then you can write a UDF that will return 1 for items satisfying the first rule, 2 for the second, 3 for the third, and `NULL` otherwise.  Your `CROSS`/`FILTER` then becomes

`res = JOIN a BY myUDF(a), b BY myUDF(b);`

Pig drops null values in `JOIN`s, so only pairs satisfying your filtering criteria will be passed.

Comment: In this case I would have done it with SPLIT already. Try something else

Comment: You try something else.  I can't read your mind on what you've tried or the reasons they won't work for you.  Your question needs more information if you want a helpful answer.

Comment: My question is really precise: I asked how to do it with a nested CROSS no more no less inside a FOR loop without prior GROUP or COGROUP.

Comment: Well that's clearly not possible, given that once you are iterating through the records of `a` you will not have anything about `b` accessible to you unless you have done some kind of `GROUP`, `COGROUP`, `JOIN`, or `CROSS` to bring it in.  You need a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

`CROSS` generates a cross-product of all the tuples in each relation.  So there is no need to have a nested `FOREACH`.  Just do the `CROSS` and then `FILTER`:

```
a: {a_attr: chararray}
b: {b_attr: int}

crossed = CROSS a, b;
crossed: {a::a_attr: chararray,b::b_attr: int}

res = FILTER crossed BY ... -- your custom filtering
```

If you have the `FILTER` immediately after the `CROSS`, you should not have (unnecessary) excessive IO trouble from the `CROSS` writing the entire cross-product to disk before filtering.  Records that get filtered will never be written at all.

Comment: I know what the CROSS does. My question arises from high cost of execution of plain cross on large data sets (see a and b have about 2 million tuples). This way a straight forward CROSS will eat all my disk space before finishing a half of an operation. So, I would not accept your answer.

Comment: Have you attempted this?  I would have guessed that using `FILTER` immediately after the `CROSS` would suppress writing of all of those tuples to disk.  Of course, if your filtering is not extremely aggressive, you may have too many tuples to write.  But that wouldn't be solved by processing a single record of `a` at a time.

Comment: That would be the case. I suppose my filtering WOULD be aggressive eliminating about .9999 of all result tuples.